# Will ios app get killed if UIThread is blocked for long time?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, ui-thread

I have a strange issue. My app gets killed if my UI thread is blocked for long time ( say 10s). I want to repeatedly take screenshots after updating view in a loop. This is a time consuming process. But my app gets killed and no memory warning is received. My question is will my app get terminated if UI Thread is blocked for long time?

Comment: no but if you have a long task you its better to make it in separate thread

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. Instead of letting apps freeze, iOS watches each app if they are taking a long time in the UI thread. Is there any reason you have to take the screenshots in a single run loop? Why not just setup a [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) callback and take just one screenshot every execution?

Comment: I want to take screenshots for sharing it via email. I want to take around 20 screenshots of my scroll view after updating it each time. Then these images are attached to email.

Comment: I found the problem, It is because the images are being cached. But i cannot see allocation while profiling nor did i receive any memory warning. Any idea how to solve it? Organizer shows my app is getting jettisoned <51b0baeda1f033328ef30e7512de299c>   28670 (jettisoned) (active)